# Integral $\int_2^4 \sqrt{16-x^2} \operatorname d\!x $

Tags: integration, geometry

We want the following integral:

$$\int_2^4 \sqrt{16-x^2} \operatorname d\!x $$

This is of course part of a circle of radius 4. I was wondering how you can find the area of that part of the circle, in a smart way.

Answer (score 4):

Drawing a picture of the area this integral representations shows that it is the difference of the area of a circular sector of radius $4$ and subtended angle $\arccos \frac{1}{2} = \frac{\pi}{3}$ and a right triangle with one vertex at $(0, 0)$ and easily computable found lengths. Both of these areas can be computed immediately with elementary formulas, sparing you from working out the (mildly unpleasant) antiderivative of the integrand.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

You want to compute the area in black. The sum of black and gray area is one sixth of the total circle area so $B+G=16\pi/6=8\pi/3$. The gray triangle's hypothenuse is equal to $4$ and its basis is $2$. So its area is $\frac12 2\times\sqrt{4^2-2^2}=\sqrt{12}=2\sqrt3$. The result is then
$$\text{Area}=\frac{8\pi}3-2\sqrt3.$$

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to compute the given integral?
Hint: Put $x=4\sin t$. Then $dx=4\cos t dt$. For $x=2$ then $\sin t=\frac{1}{2}$, so $t=\frac{\pi}{6}$. For $x=4$, then $\sin t=1$, and so $t=\frac{\pi}{2}$. So we get
$$\begin{gathered}
  \int_2^4 {\sqrt {16 - {x^2}} dx}  = \int_{\frac{\pi }
{6}}^{\frac{\pi }
{2}} {\sqrt {16 - {{\left( {4\sin t} \right)}^2}} 4\cos tdt}  = 16\int_{\frac{\pi }
{6}}^{\frac{\pi }
{2}} {\sqrt {1 - {{\sin }^2}t} \cos tdt}  
   = 16\int_{\frac{\pi }
{6}}^{\frac{\pi }
{2}} {{{\cos }^2}tdt}  = 8\int_{\frac{\pi }
{6}}^{\frac{\pi }
{2}} {\left( {1 + \cos 2t} \right)dt}  = \left. {8\left( {t + \frac{1}
{2}\sin \left( {2t} \right)} \right)} \right|_{t = \frac{\pi }
{6}}^{t = \frac{\pi }
{2}}.
\end{gathered}$$

Comment: Yes, the solution manual did it in this way too, but I couldn't come up with it myself.

Comment: @JohnPhteven As a general rule, if you see an expression of the form $\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}$ in the integrand of some integral w.r.t. $dx$, $x = a \sin t$ is a natural choice for a substitution because it simplifies just as in Cao's solution. There are similar forms for other (square roots of) sums and differences of squares involving other trigonometric (alternately, hyperbolic) functions.

Answer (score 1):

In the picture below, call $\theta$ the angle between the $x-$axis and the positive terminal green side. Then $\theta=\cos^{-1}(2/4) = \dfrac{\pi}{3}$. The entire sector (between the green segments) has area

$$A_{sector} = \dfrac{2\theta}{2\pi}\cdot \pi(4)^2 = 16\cdot \dfrac{\pi}{3}$$

The area of the isoceles triangle formed by the green lines and the boundary of the shaded region is

$$A_{triangle} = \dfrac{1}{2}bh = \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot 2\sqrt{12}\cdot 2 = 4\sqrt{3}$$

So the area of the shaded region is

$$A_{sector} - A_{triangle} = \dfrac{16\pi}{3} - 4\sqrt{3}$$

**But this is twice** the area you're looking for, so divide by 2.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$$\int^{4}_{2}\sqrt{16-x^2}\,dx=4\int^{4}_{2}\sqrt{1-(x/4)^2}\,dx$$make a change of variable $x/4=y$ and rewrite the integral as
$$16\int^{1}_{1/2}\sqrt{1-y^2}\,dy$$
Now you can make a trigonometric substitution as $1/2\leq y\leq 1$. Lets say $y=\sin{\theta}$ then the integral above reads as
$$16\int^{\pi/2}_{\pi/6}\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\theta)}\cos(\theta)\,d\theta$$
But $1-\sin^2(\theta)=\cos^2(\theta)$ and because $\pi/6\leq \theta\leq \pi/2$ then the integral can be rewritten as
$$16\int^{\pi/2}_{\pi/6}\sqrt{\cos^2(\theta)}\cos(\theta)\,d\theta=16\int^{\pi/2}_{\pi/6}\cos^2(\theta)\,d\theta$$
Notice that (use integration by parts)
\begin{align}\int^{\pi/2}_{\pi/6}\cos^2(\theta)\,d\theta=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}+\int^{\pi/2}_{\pi/6}\sin^2(\theta)\,d\theta&=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}+\int^{\pi/2}_{\pi/6}(1-\cos^2(\theta))\,d\theta\\&=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}+\frac{\pi}{3}-\int^{\pi/2}_{\pi/6}\cos^2(\theta)\,d\theta\end{align}
From the last equality you get
$$\int^{\pi/2}_{\pi/6}\cos^2(\theta)\,d\theta=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{8}+\frac{\pi}{6}$$
Multiply both sides by $16$ to get the desired result
$$16\int^{\pi/2}_{\pi/6}\cos^2(\theta)\,d\theta=-2\sqrt{3}+\frac{16\pi}{6}$$